# Subsetting a longitudinal dataset by more than one variable in R

Tags: r, subset, longitudinal

I have a longitudinal dataset in long-form, with (among others) the variables: ID, wave, currently working, occurance of chronic disease and self rated health:

```
ID              wave working Chronic SRH
451101001003    1997      1    0      0
451101020002    1997      1    0      1
451102068003    2000      1    0      1
451103041001    1997      1    0      1
451102004001    1997      0    0      0
451203011001    2004      0    0      0
421103003031    2009      1    0      0
211102009021    2000      1    1      0
```

For each participant there are an unequal amount of observations as some dropped out and others joined in later waves. As I'm looking at the effect of working conditions on health I would like to remove participants who have never worked from the dataset, but keep participants who (might have) stopped working for health reasons. In other words participants who have working = 0, and Chronic or SRH = 1.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way

```
IDs_out <- df1[rowSums(df1[, c("working", "Chronic", "SRH")]) == 0, ]$ID
df1 <- df1[!df1$ID %in% IDs_out, ]
df1
#            ID wave working Chronic SRH
#1 451101001003 1997       1       0   0
#2 451101020002 1997       1       0   1
#3 451102068003 2000       1       0   1
#4 451103041001 1997       1       0   1
#7 421103003031 2009       1       0   0
#8 211102009021 2000       1       1   0
```

---

The first step is to find the `ID`s for which columns `working`, `Chronic`, `SRH` are all `0`. In the next step we filter for `ID` from your data frame that are not in `IDs_out`.

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(451101001003, 451101020002, 451102068003, 
451103041001, 451102004001, 451203011001, 421103003031, 211102009021
), wave = c(1997L, 1997L, 2000L, 1997L, 1997L, 2004L, 2009L, 
2000L), working = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Chronic = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), SRH = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L)), .Names = c("ID", "wave", "working", "Chronic", "SRH"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```